# std::bind для функции класса с параметром

Tags: c++

Есть некоторая стандартная системная функция (в примере `Job_test`), вызывающая callback функцию с параметром.
Саму callback функцию я хочу расположить в составе класса, и потом использовать `std::bind` для ее вызова с аргументом `this`

В примере ниже `do_job2` компилируется нормально, а на `do_job1` возникает ошибка компиляции:

> no suitable user-defined conversion from "std::_Bind (ca *)>" to "ArCallBackFunction1" exists

Отличие заключается в том, что `do_job1` вызывает callback с одним параметром, а `do_job2` вызывает callback без параметра.

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно написать пример с `do_job1` ?

```
typedef std::function<void(int a)> ArCallBackFunction1;
typedef std::function<void()> ArCallBackFunction2;

void Job_test1( ArCallBackFunction1 onRequest) {  onRequest(2); };
void Job_test2( ArCallBackFunction2 onRequest) {  onRequest(); };


class ca {
  public:

  void callBack1(int a) { Serial.println("a"); };
  void callBack2() { Serial.println("a"); };

  void do_job1() {
    Job_test1( std::bind(&ca::callBack1,this));
  }

  void do_job2() {
    Job_test2( std::bind(&ca::callBack2,this));
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

typedef std::function<void(int a)> ArCallBackFunction1;
typedef std::function<void()> ArCallBackFunction2;

void Job_test1( ArCallBackFunction1 onRequest) {  onRequest(2); };
void Job_test2( ArCallBackFunction2 onRequest) {  onRequest(); };

class ca {
  public:

  void callBack1(int a) { std::cout<<"callBack1:"<<a<<'\n'; };
  void callBack2() { std::cout<<"callBack2"<<'\n'; };

  void do_job1() {
    Job_test1( std::bind(&ca::callBack1, this, std::placeholders::_1));
  }

  void do_job2() {
    Job_test2( std::bind(&ca::callBack2,this));
  }
};

int main() {

ca c;
c.do_job2();
c.do_job1();

return  0;
}
```

[std::placeholders](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/placeholders)

Comment: Большое Вам человеческое спасибо!!!!